# UICollectionView cell size in AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, collectionview

So I'm using `UICollectionView` under `AutoLayout`-enabled storyboard.
I'm trying to set cell size based on `collectionView` itself and it's based on `[collectionView: layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:]` method.
`collectionView` also depends on auto layout and it gives wrong size at first time (I assume this is before view is layouted).
I know they will have correct size after `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method is called but it causes double reloading of the `collectionView` items which makes UI glitches at run time.

Here is `[collectionView: layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:]` method of my implementation.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGSize innerSize = CGSizeMake(galleryView.frame.size.width - 80, galleryView.frame.size.height - 40);
    GLPhotoAsset *photo = [(PCOpticsPhotoPoint *)_cluster.points[indexPath.row] photo];
    CGFloat ratio = MIN(innerSize.width / photo.size.width, innerSize.height / photo.size.height);

    return CGSizeMake(photo.size.width * ratio, photo.size.height * ratio);
}
```

Comment: "I'm trying to set cell size based on collectionView" Not following you here?

Comment: @KyleTruscott I'm calculating and returning cell size based on collectionView in [collectionView: layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:] method. The problem is that this method is called before auto-layout is done.

Comment: Are you saying that the size of your cells is "related" to the rect of the collection view overall? Perhaps you should post your implementation of `[collectionView: layout: sizeForItemAtIndexPath:]`

Comment: @KyleTruscott I've edited the question to include that method.

Comment: Thanks, @pei. That makes more sense: you want your cells to be sized in relation to the overall collectionView rect. Are you calling `[galleryView reloadData]` yourself at any point?

Comment: @KyleTruscott Not really.

Comment: So you do? Where in your code do you call it? You should only call `reloadData` if your data changes later.

Comment: I don't need it. It loads at first time only.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Clip Subviews property of view is Checked . . . .

And your collectionView property cellSize must be proper in Size & Location Section . . .

May be this helps you . . .

Answer (score 0):

As you are getting a wrong layout size before *sizeForItemAtIndexPath:* is called, then goto storyboard and check the **cell size** given for these 3 - **CollectionView**, **CollectionViewCell** and **CollectionViewFlowLayout**

Make them same . (also make the size relative to the default collection view size, as u require)